# Git - I just cloned an empty rep to my projects base directory, wiping it completely. Can i undo this?

Tags: git, github, repository, clone, synchronization

I had a local folder containing my entire project, and wanted to put it up on github. I noticed i already had an old repository for that project (which was empty), so i thought, maybe i can just clone it to my local projects folder, and it'll magically merge it for me? Nope, turns out that just wipes my projects folder completely (since the rep was empty).

I'm using the [github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) app to manage it, and this is my first day using it (or git at all for that matter), which explains my lack of knowledge.

Is there any way to undo this, or am i doomed? I have months of work put into this project, and the latest backup is over four months old, so if this is possible to undo it would mean a lot to me!

**Update:** Recycle bin is empty. I just downloaded Recuva, and i'm currently running a deep scan of the folder. Hopefully it'll give me something, but i doubt it'll get me back everything. Ideas are still welcome!

**Update:** Turns out it might not have wiped the folder, and i have a newer version of the project available. My bad!

Comment: not sure i understand the description, but git stores it's repo in a hidden `.git` folder inside your project's folder. if they're still there, you may have a chance. if not, we'll see you on the other side with all the paranoid people who always make sure to have fresh backups.

Comment: @styts I'm sorry if i was unclear. I simply cloned an empty repository to a folder full of files on my computer, and since the repository was empty, it removed everything in that folder. I checked the .git folder but the old stuff was nowhere to be found, only git-stuff in there. No matter how this works out, i'm already becoming one of those paranoid people. This is horrifying!

Comment: I would be good if you can explain where you cloned, and what folder you had files. can you explain it using the actual folder names and directories?

Comment: Turns out i might be dumber than i think. I haven't worked on the project for about 3 months, and before i stopped working on it i renamed the project, and copied all of the files to a new directory with the new name, leaving the old project folder empty. I had totally forgotten that i renamed the project! Anyway, that is what i *think* happened. I don't know if git *did* wipe the old directory or not, but either way it's not an issue anymore since i have the newer files (now stored on github as well!). Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git clone shouldn't touch files already in the directory, in fact, the folder you stand in when cloning will not even be a working directory. It will create a new working directory underneath. If you try to clone into a folder that already exist git will exit with an error

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Turns out it didn't wipe the folder, like you said, and i actually have a newer version of the project available in another folder. Sorry!